# ionic 2 MenuToggle not opening on touch stay

Tags: html, ionic2

I am having a weird problem in my ionic2 app and that is when you touch the menu toggle button and stay for around > 1 seconds it is not opening the menu. I noticed I have the same problem for my other apps on ionic 1.

It is working fine in the browser when I mouse click and stay for 1-2 seconds its fine.

Can I do something to open the menu on touch down and up?

This is the code

```
<ion-header>
  <ion-navbar>
    <button ion-button menuToggle style="color: white" >
      <ion-icon name="menu"></ion-icon>
      Menu
    </button>
    <ion-title>
      <h5 style="color: white">
        Dashboard
      </h5>
    </ion-title>
  </ion-navbar>
</ion-header>
```

Comment: https://codepen.io/aftab0000/pen/vGrdme

Comment: Hi, what should be I looking for in the link?

Comment: you can check that how to open it toggle button ,